# Snap SVG sequence animations without waiting for animations to finish

Tags: animation, svg, delay, snap.svg

I want to sequence my svg animations with snap, but I don't want to wait for one animation to finish before I begin the next. Is there a way of doing this?

So far I have:

```
    var DrawmusicRoute = function () {
    musicRouteLine1.stop();
    musicRouteLine1.attr('display', '');
        musicRouteLine1.attr({
            fill: 'none',
            stroke: '#3EB799',
            strokeWidth: 17,
            strokeDasharray: musicRouteLine1_len + ' ' + musicRouteLine1_len,
            strokeDashoffset: musicRouteLine1_len,
        }).animate({
            strokeDashoffset: 0
        }, 1500, function () {
setTimeout(DrawmusicRoute2(), 3000)}
        );
    };

var DrawmusicRoute2 = function () {
     musicRouteLine2.stop();       
        musicRouteLine2.attr('display', '');
        musicRouteLine2.attr({
            fill: 'none',
            stroke: '#3EB799',
            strokeWidth: 17,
            strokeDasharray: musicRouteLine2_len + ' ' + musicRouteLine2_len,
            strokeDashoffset: musicRouteLine2_len,
        }).animate({
            strokeDashoffset: 0
        }, 500);
    };
```

Comment: If you don't want the other to finish animating first, move the setTimeout outside of the animate call, so its not dependant on that finishing ? It should be setTimeout(DrawmusicRoute2, 3000) though, not with the brackets (unless that function returns another function to all), otherwise it will call the function immediately.

Comment: That has worked really well but now I have a problem - I want a reset function that stops everything when I click outside of a certain area, but even if I use element.stop(); if I click at the wrong time the animation just continues - how can I prevent this?

Comment: I think you'll have to add a jsfiddle or similar to highlight the problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/qye8x7gw/94/ - take a look - the reset function should clear everything